# Passing data between forms (and back)

Tags: c#, winforms

On `Form1` I have a label with my total points. In `Form2` I made a store were you can purchase things with those points. However I am able to pass the points value to `Form2` but I can't figure out how I can send the points value back to `Form1`.

The code I use to send the value from Form1 to Form2.

```
Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
inventory.points = points.
```

I used the search function but since I just started writing code I find most of the given answers too confusing.

Comment: Take a look at `Application.OpenForms()`

Comment: You can set the value of a property, but you can also read its value.

Answer (score 1):

Code a constructor for form2 class as below:

```
public Form2(string strTextBox)
{
InitializeComponent(); 
label1.Text=strTextBox;
}
```

On `Form1` where you want to call `Form2` and pass a value

```
Form2 frm=new Form2(textBox1.Text);
frm.Show();
```

Add a property in `Form1` to retrieve value from textbox:

```
public string _textBox1
{
  get{return textBox1.Text;}
}
```

On `Form2`:

```
public string _textBox
{
set{label1.Text=value;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Form1 instance to Form2 when setting the points.
This requires a Form1 public variable in Form2.
e.g

```
Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
inventory.points = points;
inventory.form1 = this;
```

and when sending back in Form2

```
this.form1.points = this.points;
```

I hope this helps!